# Calculate the curvilinear integral over the segment $AB$ oriented from $A$ to $B$ $\int\limits_{AB}(x^4+4xy^3)dx+(6x^2y^2-5y^4)dy,A(-2,-1),B(0,3)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Calculate the following curvilinear integral over the segment $AB$ oriented from $A$ to $B$, where $A = (-2,-1)$ and $B = (0,3)$.

$$\int\limits_{AB}(x^4+4xy^3)dx+(6x^2y^2-5y^4)dy$$

**My attempt**: I made a parametrization
$$\begin{cases}
x = -2t, \\
y = -1 + 2t,
\end{cases} \qquad 0 \leq t \leq 1
$$

Point $A$ corresponds to $t=0$, and point $B$ corresponds to $t=1$. Also, $dx = -2dt$ and $dy = 2dt$.

\begin{align} &\int\limits_{AB}(x^4+4xy^3)dx+(6x^2y^2-5y^4)dy \\ & =
\int\limits_0^1 \left[(-2t)^4+4(-2t)(-1+2t)^3\right](-2dt)+(6(-2t)^2(-1+2t)^2 - 5(-1+2t)^4)(2dt) \\ &=\int\limits_0^1 (-32t^4 + 288t^3 - 580t^2 + 280t + 80) dt \\ &=\frac{1384}{15}\end{align}

*Did I choose the right way to solve and did I solve this integral correctly? Maybe there is an easier and faster way?*

Comment: Shouldn't the parametrisation be $x = -2 + 2t$, $y = -1 + 4t$ (with $0 \leq t \leq 1$)?

Comment: Can you show me the solution with this parameterization?

Comment: It's an almost identical solution to yours. In fact, I think you did everything correctly, aside from the parametrisation.